# Модель в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток уважаемые знатоки!  У меня такой вопрос. Я имею некий класс который является модельню в ASP.NET MVC приложении. Например такой:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    // свойство которое представляет число в виде 1,23 (2 знака после запятой)
    public string SomeDoubleValue 
    { 
        get { return _value.ToString("F"); }

        set
        { 
            double res;
            _value = Double.TryParse(value, out res) ? res : 0;                 
        }
    }

    private double _value;
    // много-много других похожих свойств и полей
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: MyDoubleValue это некое число которое должно быть представлено в виде форматированной строки. Однако смущает необходимость парсить строку для получения double в геттере. Это решение кажется каким-то некрасивым. Может есть какие-то варианты более изящные чем этот? (кроме того модель содержит довольно много таких свойств, штук 50. Я знаю что это чересчур много но это зависит к сожалению не от меня, такова структура базы данных из которой я получаю эти данные)

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте ещё один get'тер, возвращающий напрямую double. Или замените имеющийся. Зачем делать так, как не удобно?

Comment: получится что для каждого поля нужно будет делать по два свойства - одно для double другое для string что не особо хорошо. Особенно учитывая что этих полей в классе и так много

Comment: По два свойства не надо, get-теров/set-теров - возможно. Соответственно, им надо будет придумать новые имена.




Я не знаю, зачем у Вас 50 свойств и неподходящие get/set. Если они к тому же однотипные и у всех есть какой-то прикол со строками и округлением до двух знаков... Ну я сочувствую тому, кто это придумал... В этом случае можно их все заменить парой функций, принимающих дополнительно имя старого свойства (set(string name, double value) и т.п.). Не знаю, может на С# даже можно сделать чтобы ещё и обращаться можно было по старым именам